# MIDI USB/WebUSB in Chromium: Novation Components web app on ubuntu

Tags: sound, usb, chromium, udev, midi

this is a question regarding the music production device [Novation Circuit Tracks](https://novationmusic.com/circuit/circuit-tracks). You are supposed to use this [web app](https://components.novationmusic.com/) to maintain the device.
This requires a a browser with MIDI capability, such as chromium, and officially only Windows and MacOS are supported.
I already tried the web app on Windows, but I would prefer to use ubuntu.

When I open the web app in chromium on ubuntu, I am asked to allow access to MIDI devices.
However, the Circuit Tracks is not recognized by the web app (red icon top right).
In the permissions for chromium in the snap store "Access USB hardware directly" is active.
The device is properly recognized as a USB device under `lsusb` and also as a MIDI device under `amidi -l` (Novation states that the Circuit Tracks is class compliant.)

Are there some additional rules that I could try to make the web app communicate with the device? It may well be possible that the web app simply does not work on ubuntu.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Novation Circuit is recognized flawlessly by Chrome, but not by Chromium. Therefore, just install Chrome if you want to use Ubuntu for the Components software.